# AEM create package with 1 node only

Tags: aem, crx

Is it possible in AEM to create a package for /home/users, but with ONLY 1 node under each user ?

Example, I have 100 users in AEM and every user has custom data in 1 node only. Can I fetch only this node for all the 100 users in a package ?
The structure of user nodes is like this:

```
/home/users/3/3_alphanumeric_id/customNode
```

I dont want to add 100 filters to the package as it will be a very long task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACS Commons has a [Query Packager](https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/packagers/query-packager/index.html) tool. The documentation on the page is pretty self explanatory.

If ACS Commons is not an option, another strategy would be to edit the filters of a content package on your machine, upload it, then build to pick up the nodes. The filters are configured in `META-INF/vault/filter.xml` and are in simple filter elements like `<filter root="/home/users/3/3_alphanumeric_id/customNode"/>`.

You can do the query to find all of your nodes in crxde, use the json it requests from the network traffic, and use a text editor to rewrite the json into the filter elements.

[image: getting the json for a query]

Comment: Thanks ....This was extremely helpful !!! I tweaked the query results from json response and voila !